# Where are these two hills with fall foliage in Saguenay QC?

Tags: identify-this, factoids

[The image below](http://www.cruisesaintlawrence.com/EN/stopovers/passengers/6/Saguenay.aspx) was taken by Mathieu Dupuis.

[image: photo]

Where is this?

Comment: Have you contacted the photographer ?

Comment: This is close to impossible and I do not see any 'practical travel' use in finding the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location is:

**The Saint Lawrence river, Quebec**

On [this website](https://cruiseable.com/places-in-canada-to-see-gorgeous-fall-foliage), I found the exact same photo with the caption:

> Fall foliage on the Saint Lawrence River.

It is difficult to pinpoint where this photo was taken along the river exactly as the river is 1,197 km long.

[This article](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1988-08-14-tr-564-story.html) provides some places where you can view fall foliage on the St Lawrence river.